# Custom attributes values not getting added to flat table

Tags: attributes, collection, index, flat-catalog

I'm having several product attributes that I need inside the flat table (or as an alternative: joining them into my collection from basic eav table). Therefore I set them to "Used in Product Listing" = yes.

Now this works for some attributes but some won't get filled. I compared with another attribute that is also a simple varchar/text input with same settings which gets correctly filled into the flat table.

Any guesses why some attributes get indexed and some not while the only difference is the name and for one that works that is set to be used in quick search?

Comment: Is the column created and not filled? Or is it omit?

Comment: Column was created but always resulted in _NULL_.

Comment: Are you sure, that the store view value exists?